# make scatter plot of each variable in pandas dataframe separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make separate scatter plots between each column in a dataframe `X` and `y`. Next, I want to print every separate scatter plot on a page in a pdf file. My code looks like:

```
# get hist for every column
pp2 = PdfPages('scatters.pdf')
# pp.savefig()
for i, col in enumerate(X.columns):
    # create scatterplot
    plt.scatter(x=X[col], y=y, )
    plt.xlabel(col)
    plt.ylabel('Header')

    # print to pdf
   pp2.savefig()
plt.clf()
pp2.close()
```

However, this returns the scatter plots over each other in one plot. Does anyone know how to make every scatter plot on a separate plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have separate plots, add **`plt.figure()`** as the first line of code in the `for` loop like so.

```py
for i, col in enumerate(X.columns):
    plt.figure()
    # create scatterplot
    plt.scatter(x=X[col], y=y, )
    ...
```